# optimization problem maximizing trace of a matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to solve the following problem:

$\max_{X} \operatorname{trace} \left( AX^TBX\right).$

A and B is given.

$A$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix and $B$ is a $n\times n$ nonnegative positive definite symmetric matrix.

$X$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix.

Are there any experts aware of this optimization problem?We kindly ask for your cooperation.

Comment: This is a simple unconstrained quadratic programming problem in terms of the elements of $x=\mbox{diag}(X)$.

Comment: It is either zero or unbounded, so there is not much to do.

Comment: This looks much more standard if $x$ is treated simply as a vector, then the function is a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) $x^TMx$ with a matrix $M$ expressible in terms of $A$'s and $B$'s entries. And you probably want to fix the norm of $x$, say $\|x\|=1$, otherwise the problem is trivial, as copper.hat pointed out.

Comment: Thank you very much！I will research about quadratic form and unconstrained quadratic programming problem.